# Deploying A Static Website to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have made a static website `(HTML, CSS, Javascript)` which i would like to deploy to Azure. Is there another choice for a static website on Azure rather than Web App. I mean if we consider pricing what choice have i got? And why i should choose it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also have a free webapp (No custom domains or shared for 4.99 per month) and deploy using FTP.

Comment: Free? Gratis? Is that always enabled?

Answer (score -1):

If you really do only have static content, you can just upload it to a blob storage. With containers, you have to option to mimic folders (and also with the actual file names), you can have backups, replication and so on. You can even attach custom domains to the blob store. And compared to a Web App, they are a lot cheaper.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/

**[Edit after almost two years :) ]**

So I guess I was a little too quick to jump to answering this question back then. As the comments pointed out, there was no "default document" when using blob storage. But now there is: *Static website hosting* is in preview for blobs. Check out the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

Comment: You cannot have a "default" landing place with blob storage. So, unless someone goes to `yoursite.com/default.html` it won't work.